# How to make an Illusioner do extra damage

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to make a modified Illusioner as the final boss of my dungeon, but I'm having trouble increasing his damage. 
I have tried both these commands:

`/summon minecraft:illusioner ~ ~ ~ {HandItems:[{Count:1,id:"bow",Damage:8}],Attributes:[{Name:"generic.maxHealth",Base:100}],Health:100.0f,}`

`/summon minecraft:illusioner ~ ~ ~ {HandItems:[{Count:1,id:"bow"}],Attributes:[{Name:"generic.maxHealth",Base:100},{name:"generic.attackDamage,Base:8}],Health:100.0f,}`

Neither of those have affected his damage (I can increase his HP just fine though). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Give him the strength effect. It will increase his attack damage.

Comment: 1. `HandItems` always has two items. 2. `Attributes` must be in the item data. 3. No comma before the closing bracket. 4. There's probably more. If your commands don't work, at least post the error message, don't just say "it doesn't work". In general give as much detail as possible and try things on your own. See also the [tour] and [how-to-ask]. You should also at least look up some example commands, there are a lot that are similar to what you want.

Comment: I have tried various things, is there maybe a bug with illusioners? I threw a splash potion of strength at one and it did not increase the damage output of the illusioner. (And some other things where I am not as sure if it is supposed to work, but the splash potion really should work, right?)

Answer (score 1):

There may be a bug in the game, I am not sure though.

You can however give the illusioner an enchanted bow.

```
/summon minecraft:illusioner ~ ~ ~ {HandItems:[{Count:1,id:"minecraft:bow",tag:{Enchantments:[{id:"minecraft:power",lvl:10s}]}}],Attributes:[{Name:"generic.maxHealth",Base:100}],Health:100.0f}
```